# How are existing subplot axes retrieved using subplot2grid/gridspec in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I have problems accessing existing subplot in a Matplotlib figure when specifying plot locations using gridspec directly, or alternatively, subplot2grid. Regular subplot specs, e.g. add_subplot(211), returns existing axes if any. Using gridspec/subplot2grid seems to destroy any existing axes. How do I retrieve the existing axes objects using gridspec/subplot2grid? Is this intended behaviour or am I missing something here? I would like a solution where I do not have to define own placeholders for the axes objects.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y1 = np.cos(x)
y2 = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.plot(x,y1, '-b')
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax.plot(x,y2, '-b')
ax = fig.add_subplot(211) #here, the existing axes object is retrieved
ax.plot(x,y2, '-r')

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax.plot(x,y1, '-b')
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
ax.plot(x,y2, '-b')
# using gridspec (or subplot2grid), existing axes
# object is apparently deleted
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax.plot(x,y2, '-r')

plt.show()
```

Comment: The simplest way is to just keep a reference to them your self.

Comment: Yeah, easily done and I guess I'll have stick to that solution so far. A unified behaviour for add_plot etc. for the various ways to specify the subplot format is still needed though, IMO.

Comment: The best place to express that view in an issue on github ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a subtle bug with the magic of how `add_subplot` determines if a an axes exists.  It boils down to this fact:

```
In [220]: gs[0, 0] == gs[0, 0]
Out[220]: False
```

which is because `gridspec.__getitem__` returns a new object every time you call it and `SubplotSpec` does not overload `__eq__` so python checks 'is this the same object in memory' when searching for existing axes.

That is what is wrong, however my naive attempt to fix it by adding a `__eq__` to a `SubplotSpec` and monkey patching `matplotlib.gridspec.SubplotSpec` didn't work (I don't have time to figure out why), but if you add

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return all((self._gridspec == other._gridspec,
                self.num1 == other.num1,
                self.num2 == other.num2))
```

to `class SubplotSpec(object):` in `matplotlib/gridspec.py` ~L380 and re-installing from source works as expected.

[PR to fix this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2597) which seems to break all sorts of other things.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and effort in correcting the issue.